# border-radius for table doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css

Everything works just as it should in Internet Explorer and Chrome. But in Firefox there is no rounded corners at all. Does anybody have a clue what the problem might be? I've tried to remove the -moz- and -webkit- tags but it doesn't make any difference. Border-radius should be supported by the latest version of Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Any solution?

Code:

```
.evenOddColoursLight tr:not(.noEvenOddColoursLight), .evenOddColour1L{
background-color:#f6f6f4;
}
.evenOddColoursLight tr:nth-child(odd):not(.noEvenOddColoursLight), .evenOddColour2L{
background-color:#efeeeb;
}

.forum-table th:first-child {
-moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.forum-table th:last-child {
-moz-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;

}

.forum-table tr:last-child td:first-child {
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.forum-table tr:last-child td:last-child {
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;

}

.forum-table table tr:last-child td {
border-bottom: none;
}

.forum-table td {
padding:10px;
}

.forum-table th {
padding:5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
```

All the at is found at code: http://jsfiddle.net/SUhsD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing the `.evenOddColoursLight` and added:

```
.forum-table tr:nth-child(odd) td, .forum-table tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #efeeeb;
}

.forum-table tr:nth-child(even) td, .forum-table tr:nth-child(even) th{
  background-color: #f6f6f4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just play with individual cells style. Working example on Firefox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/AyKE7/

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 4px 7px;
}

/* hover */
tr:hover th,
tr:hover td {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

/* hover, left cell */
tr:hover th {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

/* hover, last cell on the right */
tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: I know. Just for laugh. And click to accept the answer, if the solution worked for you.

Comment: It is not my question I'm just browsing. And I'm disappointed to see the `HashTag` is creeping into S.O :(

Comment: Solved it by removing the .evenOddColoursLight and added:
    .forum-table tr:nth-child(odd) td, .forum-table tr:nth-child(odd)         th{
        background-color:#efeeeb;
    }
    .forum-table tr:nth-child(even) td, .forum-table tr:nth-child(even) th{
    background-color:#f6f6f4;
    }